# Aesthetic URL problem: Website from server02 should look like its on a subdirectory of the main site from server01

Tags: domains, subdomain, url-rewriting, ip-address, subdirectory

`www.example.com` is on `server01` with IP address `192.0.2.123`

`abc.example.com` is on `server02` with IP address `192.0.2.21`

I actually do not want the subdomain `abc`. Ideally I want it at `www.example.com/abc`. I want to have a more cohesive website for usability and aesthetics. For non-technical people, having the content in a sub-directory feels that you are still on the same site compared to going to a sub-domain.

My problem is that the code for the subdomain site (Site2) is on `server02` with a different IP. I cannot use just 1 server for the 2 sites: Site1 is using Apache, MySql, and PHP for PHP websites and static websites. Site 2 is a webapp that uses nginx, ruby and postgresql. Maintenance wise, IMHO, it is easiest to have site02 on a separate server. But as I said, it would be great if it can be visited by the end-user in a sub-directory of the main domain.

Is there a a way for me to achieve this?

Comment: What is not aesthetic about a sub-domain?

Answer (score 2):

In order for two servers to share the exact same domain (www.example.com) and your website to work properly the two servers would need to be a mirror of eachother in terms of content and functionality, ideally linked to the same databases and storage behind the scenes since the same user may access either server within the same session. This would be setup by creating an `A` DNS record for each server IP address for the subdomain `www`.

This isn't what you're after however since your servers have different functionality and software environment. This kind of routing cannot be done with a subfolder unfortunately.

Two potential solutions for you to consider:

- You could setup some kind of proxy script on `server01` which essentially forwards incoming requests onto `server02` and then forwards the responses from `server02` back to the requesting connection. This would technically achieve what you want but you'll be making `server01` do more processing than should be required.
- You could setup a redirection script in the subfolder on `server01` so that if your end-users enter `https://www.example.com/abc` or `https://www.example.com/abc/` into their browser address bar your script then redirects them automatically to `https://abc.example.com/`. For this you could return the HTTP header: `HTTP/1.0 301 Location: http://abc.example.com/` using whichever scripting language you prefer and that works on `server01`.

Comment: Specifically "some kind of proxy" would be a "reverse proxy".  Both Apache and Nginx can easily be configured as a reverse proxy to show content from another server.